# Can I use "about" instead of "over"?

Tags: prepositions

> A Debate Over the Physics of Time.

Can I change "OVER" to "ABOUT" in the above text to mean same context?

Comment: Not only yes, but here *about* would be more appropriate than *over.*

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Could explain me why?

Comment: [Google N-Grams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=debate+about%2Cdebate+over&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) suggests that in the US "debate about" and "debate over" are of similar popularity (in its collection of sources), while in the UK "debate about" is twice as common.

Comment: @JorgeLuiz Broadly yes but not here. Both the original and your own follow-up Question belong not here but in English Language Learners.

Comment: @StuartF "over" sounds much more natural to me, so this is likely a split between AmE and BrE.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can replace OVER with ABOUT and ON.

1. A debate about the physics of time.
2. A debate on the physics of time.

Comment: Is there some difference when using them? If so, what is?